# Reduce textfield width & display comment box below text

Tags: html, css

we have contact-us page like this

[image]

I want to  chnage like this

[image]

when i tried `width : 75 %` , its working only for `Name`

```
input[type=email], input[type=search], input[type=number], input[type=password], input[type=tel], input[type=text] {
    height: 32px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
<!-- <div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Us') ?></h1>
</div> -->
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts/index/post'); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post" class="scaffold-form">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
        <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name')) ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email')) ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="telephone"class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box required-entry">
                    <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone')) ?>" value="" class="input-text required-entry validate-digits" type="tel" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="wide">
                <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment')) ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit')) ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

I want to place 4 textfields at the center of the white background

Comment: Please provide the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here updated css for width and display of comment box.

```css
/*Width of the form */
input, textarea{
 width: 75%;
}

/*Form Inputs Customization */
input[type=text],
input[type=email], 
input[type=tel] {
    height: 34px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 15px;
}

/*Submit Button */
input[type=submit] {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: can you please provide me line number for email, telephone and comment, also i want to display comment box under text "comment"

Comment: I have updated the css code you can copy and past in your local css file..you don't to need worry...it will not conflict with your other css attributes.

Comment: i placed this code as both internal and external css, but it didt worked for me, is i ned to use !important ? if so where ?

Comment: Yeah you can add this code in only one way internal or external. If you are using external css put it on top of the css file inside so that you can skip "!important"

Comment: i placed code in top of the external css file, but still it didt worked for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114733/discussion-between-sayed-rafeeq-and-nsdlfefinedieicbe).

Answer (score 1):

Just set

```
input,textarea{
 width:75%; /*Whatever you want */
}
```

Comment: can you please tell line numbers , i have to use `width:75%` because its not working for me.

Comment: thnaks for support